# SQL select subquery that returns boolean value based on case statement

Tags: sql, subquery, case

I have 2 tables and I want the case statement subquery to set the returned value string value 'Rural' if no match and 'Urban' if true.  I need the query to lookup table 2 to see if the City name exists.

Currently my query always returns the false value 'RURAL'

```
, CASE --This CASE is identifying Urban communities as listed in the contract, and leaving the rest as Rural.

WHEN t1.city in (select top 1 city from t1
                 left join t2 on t2.city2 = t1.city
                where t2.city2 = t1.city 
                              ) 
            then 'Urban'
            ELSE 'Rural' 
          end as URBAN_RURAL

select    t1.city
    , t2.city2
    , CASE --This CASE is identifying Urban communities and leaving the rest as Rural.
WHEN Exists (select top 1 from t1 where t1.city = t2.city2) 
            then 'Urban'
            ELSE 'Rural' 
      end as Urban_Status; 

from t1  with (nolock)
    left join t2 with (nolock)
    on t1.city = t2.city
```

I want to use the lookup table as we may be modifying what qualifies as a City and just add or remove names from that table t2.  So if the case statement can return the Urban string value for matching results in both tables, and rural for unmatched, that would be ideal.

sample results would be

```
City    City2     UrbanRural
Orono   NULL      Rural
Bangor  Bangor    Urban
Machias Null      Rural
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also, sample data and expected results are helpful.

Comment: Does T1 just hold the urban cities and T2 the rural? It's very difficult to figure out what you need just based on a query that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I will keep those quesstions in mind, thanks very much for your response.  I figured out why my query wasnt working.  In t2 table the City names had an extra space in all of the names, so SQL was not joining the 2 tables from the get go.

Comment: Aside: An `exists` query requires, but ignores, the _select list_. That said, `top 1` just confuses the reader but doesn't affect performance. You could just as well select `1`, `0`, `NULL`, `1 / 0` or `42`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. But not really sure without sample expected results.

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         ( SELECT 'URBAN'
             FROM T2
            WHERE T1.city = T2.city
         ), 'RURAL' ) AS CITY_TYPE,
       T1.*
  FROM T1
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion now to see if that will give me the anticipated results.  I updated my expected results as well, thanks for tip on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already joining `t1` and `t2` in your `FROM` clause, you don't need an in-line sub-query at all.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.city(2?) IS NULL THEN 'URBAN'
    ELSE 'RURAL'
  END AS URBAN_RURAL
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 
  ON t1.city = t2.city
```

Note: `NOLOCK` removed - Put it back if you *really* need it, but see [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thank you for the NoLock note.  where this data is loaded Monthly, our queries are not concerned with uncommitted data.  Great idea though